# How to find site base URL in my javascripts?

Tags: javascript, php, url

What is the best practice to provide Javascripts with URL's for things such as Ajax calls?
My javascripts live in the public folder `website/js/` and need to get the `website/` part so that I can structure the URL for my Ajax calls from there.

Is there any best methods for doing this? I was thinking of having something in the html such as:

var base = ;

Are there better methods?

Answer (score 2):

Just use window.location.origin

If you need the slash "/" at the end:

```
var baseUrl = window.location.origin + "/";
```

Comment: if the url is = http : // www. example.com/route/hello/something, then window.location.origin returns http://www.sitename.com.

Comment: @kbworkshop he just wants the base url, hence window.location.origin is correct

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the fully qualified path.  Start your URL with a `/` and use relative paths.

```
var full_path     = 'http://www.google.com/js/some_js_file.js';
var relative_path = '/js/some_js_file.js';
```

These are equivalent if you're viewing a page at www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below code

```
var base_url='http://'+window.location.host+'/';
```